# How to change the stringformat of Oxyplot track value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting, axis-labels, oxyplot

If I change the stringformat of axis, it works for the axis (see the black circle of the picture). But how can I change the stringformat of the track value (the red circle)?

[image]

Comment: See https://oxyplot.userecho.com/en/communities/1/topics/583-trackerformatstring-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `DefaultTrackerTemplate`. Here a small example that shows you the way:

```
<Grid>
    <oxy:Plot Title="AAA">
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Title="Left: " />
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom"  Title="Bottom: " />
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries x:Name="ls" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:Plot.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <oxy:TrackerControl Position="{Binding Position}"  
                                BorderThickness="1">
                    <oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                        <StackPanel >
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XAxis.Title}" Foreground="Red" />
                                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding DataPoint.X}" Foreground="Red" />
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding YAxis.Title}" Foreground="Green" />
                                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding DataPoint.Y}" Foreground="Green" 
                                       FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                </oxy:TrackerControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </oxy:Plot.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
    </oxy:Plot>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should work, but it overwrites the default template. I actually like the axis titles to be included as in the default template (the area I erased in the picture in my question).

Comment: You should bind the Text property. See the answer. I updated it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to answer my own question based on Ramin's hint to me.

I dug into the source code a little bit, and found out there is a `TrackerFormatString` that I can change:

```
<oxy:LineSeries TrackerFormatString="{}{0}&#x0a;{1}: {2:0.0}&#x0a;{3}: {4:0.0}"/>
```

Please note the `&#x0a;` in my code, that how a newline char is input in XAML.

Please also note the `{}` in the very beginning, that's kind of escape char in XAML.

if in c#, it's just:

```
{0}\n{1}: {2:0.0}\n{3}: {4:0.0}
```

Comment: This is nice too.

Comment: more discussion at http://discussion.oxyplot.org/forums/1-general/topics/583-trackerformatstring-question/

Comment: The current link to the discussion - https://oxyplot.userecho.com/en/communities/1/topics/583-trackerformatstring-question